# vue-router.esm.js?fe87:565 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i tried to install vuejs and while running a sample code i am unable to get the output
my index.html

```
             <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html>
               <head>
               <meta charset="utf-8">
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
           <title>vuejs</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                 <script src ="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
          </head>
        <body>
        <div id="app">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
         </div>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
       </body>
        </html>
```

my app.js is below

```
    var app=new Vue({
       el:'#app',
        data:{
           name :'hello',
          }
             });
```

i get the error as below. please let me know watz wrong in it

```
    vue-router.esm.js?fe87:565 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router
   at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
   at Function.install (VM4614 vue-router.esm.js:565)
   at Function.Vue.use (vue.js:4738)
   at eval (VM4614 vue-router.esm.js:2668)
   at Object../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js (VM4578 app.js:922)
  at __webpack_require__ (VM4578 app.js:679)
  at fn (VM4578 app.js:89)
  at eval (VM4613 index.js:2)
  at Object../src/router/index.js (VM4578 app.js:1070)
  at __webpack_require__ (VM4578 app.js:679)
```

Comment: Can you check if app is getting loaded twice on the same page ?

Comment: only once its loaded

Comment: Have you used vue-router ?

Comment: no..where to use it?

Comment: above error message shows here: /src/router/index.js.

Comment: sorry i didnt get u

Comment: Is there  index.js file inside ./src/router in your app ?

Comment: ya..where should i add there?

Comment: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-routing-with-vue-router-4c428fabb078